# Displaying international email characters over ssh correctly

Tags: linux, unix, internationalization, mailx

I am using Debian with a standard sendmail and bsd-mailx configuration. My international characters arrive OK (at least Gmail interprets them correctly), but the other way around fails miserably. With default encoding settings (ISO-8859-1), the line

> Here is my resumé.

becomes

> Here is my resum=E9.

But even changing the "Outgoing message encoding" to UTF-8 (which is the encoding used by my locale) does not improve things, as I get

> Here is my resum=C3=A9.

Is there a silver bullet for this? I should point out that I'm accessing my server via SSH, just in case it helps.

Server and client have `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` set.

Comment: Hmm, what's the locale of your terminal? `env|grep LANG` ... also what terminal emulator are you using? For example PuTTY lets you set the encoding at the client-side to match that of the server.

Comment: I get `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, which is the same thing I get on the server. In fact, I have no problems when I type these characters over the SSH connection. I'm using the gnome-terminal under the awesome WM.

Comment: Sorry for the unfinished reply that was published unintentionally. I edited my first reply.

Comment: Clearly looks like a translation/representation issue. But I don't have the setup to help, you'll have to wait for someone else to pick up your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found wise advice [here](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/development/programming-scripting/419802-charset-problem-mailx.html): simply go for heirloom-mailx instead of bsd-mailx. That did it for me.